# I'm having trouble upgrading to jQuery UI 1.8.11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

I have an old version of jQuery and the jQuery user interface (ui) 1.3.1 to be exact.
I'm upgrading to jQuery UI 1.8.11 which I thought would be straightforward as somewhere they have fixed some problems with ie9.

So I've swapped over the function files and css files and no dice on ie9 also the dialog boxes are opening in the top left not the middle like before.

Any ideas on why in some situations it doesn't work in ie9? It's mainly the sortable that is presenting problems -  or how to get the javascript errors on the page up. 
Seems to be one thing they have missed.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @meagar - why did you retag this back to javascript and jquery instead of jquery-ui? The question is specifically about jQuery UI, not jQuery, and anything tagged jQuery is inherently javascript, so that really isn't necessary. Just curious.

Comment: Sorry just wanting to tag it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it was bg plugin that we had for ie6 and other browsers to make the dialogs work - remove and hey presto.

Comment: Had same problem, jquery.bgiframe.min.js was causing a "unrecognizeable character" in jquery. Removed that include and I stopped getting errors in the IE9 console, and things started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI 1.8.11 requires jQuery **1.3.2** or later.

See http://jqueryui.com/